# how to provide string constants for drop down lists in jsp

Tags: string, jsp, drop-down-menu

In a jsp page ,I am presenting the customer with drop down lists to select creditcardtype,expiration month,expiration year of credit card. 
I am looking at ways the necessary strings  for this can be put ,other than hardcoding them in html.

thanks

mark

```
<tr>
<td>
    <select id="creditCardType" title="select card type" name="creditCardType">
        <option value="M0">MasterCard</option>
        <option value="D0">Discover</option>
        <option value="J0">JCB</option>
        <option value="I0">Diners Club</option>
        <option value="A0">American Express</option>
        <option value="V0">Visa</option>
        <option value="V">Amazon.com Visa</option>
        <option value="G21">Amazon.com Store Card</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Expiration Date</td>
<td> 
                     <select id="cardexpiryMonth" name="cardexpiryMonth">
                        <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
                        <option value="02" >02</option>
                        <option value="03" >03</option>
                        <option value="04" >04</option>
                        <option value="05" >05</option>
                        <option value="06" >06</option>
                        <option value="07" >07</option>
                        <option value="08" >08</option>
                        <option value="09" >09</option>
                        <option value="10" >10</option>
                        <option value="11" >11</option>
                        <option value="12" >12</option>
                      </select>
</td>
<td>
                    <select id="cardexpiryYear" name="cardexpiryYear">
                        <option value="2011" >2011</option>
                        <option value="2012" selected="selected">2012</option>
                        <option value="2013" >2013</option>
                        <option value="2014" >2014</option>
                        <option value="2015" >2015</option>
                        <option value="2016" >2016</option>
                        <option value="2017" >2017</option>
                        <option value="2018" >2018</option>
                        <option value="2019" >2019</option>
                        <option value="2020" >2020</option>
                        <option value="2021" >2021</option>
                        <option value="2022" >2022</option>
                        <option value="2023" >2023</option>
                        <option value="2024" >2024</option>
                        <option value="2025" >2025</option>
                        <option value="2026" >2026</option>

                        <option value="2027" >2027</option>
                        <option value="2028" >2028</option>
                        <option value="2029" >2029</option>
                        <option value="2030" >2030</option>
                        <option value="2031" >2031</option>
                      </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it are application wide constants, just put them in the application scope during application startup. The application scope is represented by the object being an attribute of `ServletContext`. See also [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi)

## CDI available?

If CDI happens to be available in your environment (i.e. you're running a normal JEE server such as WildFly, Payara, TomEE, etc), then just use an `@ApplicationScoped` bean instead of a `ServletContextListener`.

```
@Named @ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    private Map<String, String> creditCardTypes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 
        creditCardTypes = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        creditCardTypes.put("M0", "MasterCard");
        creditCardTypes.put("D0", "Discover");
        // ...
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCreditCardTypes() {
        return creditCardTypes;
    }
}
```

*(note that I used `LinkedHashMap` as it maintains insertion order in contrary to `HashMap`)*

This way it's available as `${data.creditCardTypes}` by EL in any JSP.  You can then use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it. It also supports iterating over a `Map` and each iteration will give a [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods which are accessible in EL as well.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<select id="creditCardType" title="select card type" name="creditCardType">
    <c:forEach items="${data.creditCardTypes}" var="creditCardType">
        <option value="${creditCardType.key}">${creditCardType.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

## No CDI available?

If CDI is not available (i.e. you're not running a normal JEE server, such as Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow, etc, and you don't want to [install CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat) for some reason), then you can use the `init()` method of an arbitrary servlet or, better, a `ServletContextListener`.

```
@WebListener
public class Data implements ServletContextListener {

    private Map<String, String> creditCardTypes;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) { 
        creditCardTypes = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        creditCardTypes.put("M0", "MasterCard");
        creditCardTypes.put("D0", "Discover");
        // ...

        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("data", this);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCreditCardTypes() {
        return creditCardTypes;
    }
}
```

This way it's also available as `${data.creditCardTypes}` by EL in any JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<select id="creditCardType" title="select card type" name="creditCardType">
    <c:forEach items="${data.creditCardTypes}" var="creditCardType">
        <option value="${creditCardType.key}">${creditCardType.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I have updated the question a bit..will be thankful any suggestions

Comment: If you have a new question, please do not reuse an existing, unrelated and already answered question, but just press `Ask Question` on the right top.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring (2.5/3.0) then have a look at @ModelAttribute